# Is there any rule to tell me when to add "it" to a sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I often commit mistakes like this:

> What a terrible thing [it] must be for an earthquake to hit right on
>   your birthday.

Is there any rule to tell me when to add "it" to a sentence?

Answer (score 2):

English requires an explicit subject in sentences and clauses; the only exception is the second-person imperative, where the "you" is implied ("Go away!"). Without the "it" in this sentence, "must be" has no subject.